# Yacc/flex syntax error

Tags: c++, flex-lexer, yacc

**EDIT: changed the Polinom rule**

I tried writing a simple compiler that's going to recognize polynomials and print them out. Although it does that, just as intended, it spits out a syntax error write after printing out the polynomial. What bothers me with problems such as these is not being able to figure out whether it's the lexer or parser causing all the fuss.

`parser.ypp`

```
%{

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

extern int yylex();

void yyerror(string s) {
    cerr << s << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


%}

%union {
    double d;
    vector<double> *niz;
    }

%token <d> num_token
%type <niz> NizBrojeva  

%%

Program:    Program '\n' Polinom
        | Polinom
        ;


Polinom:    '<' NizBrojeva '>'  { 
                        vector<double>::iterator i;
                        int k = 0;
                        for(i = $2->begin(); i != $2->end(); i++, k++) {
                            if (*i == 0)
                                continue;

                            if (k == 0) {
                                cout << *i;
                                continue;
                            }

                            if (*i > 0)
                                cout << " + " << abs(*i) << "x";
                            if (*i < 0)
                                cout << " - " << abs(*i) << "x";
                            if (k != 1)
                                cout << "^" << k;
                        }       

                        cout << endl;                   

                    }
        | // <-------------------------------------------- That's all I added
        ;

NizBrojeva: NizBrojeva ',' num_token    { $1->push_back($3); $$ = $1; }
        | num_token         { $$ = new vector<double>(); $$->push_back($1); }
        ;



%%


int main() {
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

`lexer.l`

```
%option noyywrap
%option noinput
%option nounput

%{

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#include "parser.tab.hpp"

%}

DIGIT [0-9]

%%

([+|-])?{DIGIT}+(\.{DIGIT}*)?       { yylval.d = atof(yytext); return num_token; }
[<>,\n]             { return *yytext; }
[ \t]               { }
.           { cerr << "Leksicka greska: neprepoznat karakter " << *yytext << endl;
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

%%
```

The test example is a text file with one line in it: `<1, -3, 0, -1.3, 6>`

Comment: Let me guess, that single line in the file have a *newline* after it? Now what do the rule for `Program` say happens after a newline? Perhaps you should add a token for `EOF` and have that in the parser rules?

Comment: Just a shot into blue: It couldn't hurt to put `\r` into the flex rule for spaces (i.e. `[ \t]` -> `[ \t\r]`). This would at least help on Windows and if input file is opened in binary mode...

Comment: Actually, no , I tried with both a newline and without it> the error is still the same. Also tried with `\r` just now, no success.

Comment: And you're sure the editor you use to edit the input file doesn't automatically add a trailing newline? If you type it out in a console, is the newline there?

Comment: ^ Tried that just now, nothing helped. I use gedit in Ubuntu, never had any issues such as that before. Not that just with parsers, but in general.

Comment: To allow empty lines as well may be: `Program : Polinom '\n' Program | '\n' Program | Polinom`.

Comment: Actually, I just added an empty rule to `Polinom` and it worked, can anyone explain this ?

Comment: Could you, please, [edit] your question and show the update of `Polinom`?

Comment: Thinking twice about `Program : Polinom '\n' Program | Polinom`: `Program : Program '\n' Polinom | Polinom` should work as well (and is preferable because yacc "likes" left-recursion more than right-recursion.) Thus, the hint with the `EOF` might be essential.

Comment: The empty alternative for `Polinom` covers empty lines in `Program`. Before this change, the last input line had to have a polynom (and had not to end with `\n`).

Comment: That's what bothers me: so even though there is specifically one line, with no `\n` character at the end, I still had to add the rule. So does that mean this is  gedit's doing ?

Comment: To find out what your file does really contain use e.g. `hexdump -c`.

Comment: @monolith937, the default rule for lex/flex is `.|\n`. Try to replace your `.` rule with this and check.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, gedit always adds a newline character `\n` at the end of its files. Seems there's no way of preventing that. Adding an empty rule to Polinom in parser.ypp, sidesteps that issue by allowing Polinom to beceome just a newline.